# Add or delete rows when a button is clicked in infopath

Tags: infopath, field-controls

I have a row with some multiple selection listbox and a dropdown listbox. i need to get a new rows when a button is clicked with that two controls on that new row. How come i achieve this..

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are "certain" controls? Please edit your question and describe in more detail what you want to achieve. Post screenshots of the form and of the data source, so we can see what the structure is.

Comment: @teylyn  i tried using repeating table but the values selected are getting similar.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are describing. Please post a screenshot of the form and a screenshot of the data structure.